# How to pass an authenticated identity across web sites?

Tags: authentication, claims-based-identity

I have a web site with an initial login page, on this page I'm using a claims based identity which is authenticated when a user successfully logs in.

This all works fine, from this main site I have a number of 'sub sites' (that also require logins), and I'm looking to use the same authenticated identity to log into these (e.g. so a user does not have to enter login details every time).

Is there a way to pass the initial authenticated claims-based identity to these sites securely? If so could someone point me in the direction of any useful material on this?

EDIT

Just to clarify in response to the answers below, I am currently using Single Sign On and have this working as follows.

User logins in to https://mywebsite.com/loginsite with Single Sign On. Claims-based identity is authenticated.

What I'm wanting to do is use this same authenticated Claims to log in to the following url in the same domain:

https://mywebsite.com/website1

But whenever I try to access the Identity the authentication is false. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned is generally referred to as SSO (Single Sign On). See the Auth0 page [How to Implement Single Sign On](https://auth0.com/learn/how-to-implement-single-sign-on/) for one way to achieve this.

> **Single Sign On works by having a central server, which all the applications trust**. When you login for the first time a cookie gets created on this central server. Then, whenever you try to access a second application, you get redirected to the central server, if you already have a cookie there, you will get redirected directly to the app with a token, without login prompts, which means you’re already logged in.

(emphasis is mine)

---

**Disclosure**: I work at Auth0.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using SSO and have this working as a first step, but am missing something as it does not work for subsequent applications in the same domain, so appears I have missed something (see edit above).

Comment: The actual implementation details will depend on the technologies involves, if all your application are within the same domain one available approach is to create a cookie that identifies your authenticated identity so that others site can use it. My advice if for you to create a question focusing on the technologies you want to use.